# Problems trying to replace disk in truenas mirrored boot

Tags: zfs, truenas

I have a TrueNAS box (TrueNAS-13.0-U5.3) and my boot pool is mirrored 32GB flash drives. One of the drives, da2, is getting errors, so I want to replace it.
I already have a new drive plugged in, da1, not part of any pool (as far as I know) but when I use zpool replace, or the same thing in the GUI, I get this error: `"already in replacing/spare config; wait for completion or use 'zpool detach'"`

```bash
% sudo zpool replace freenas-boot gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c /dev/da1
cannot replace gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c with /dev/da1: already in replacing/spare config; wait for completion or use 'zpool detach'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this and move on, using my da1. I don't see da1 as part of anything (but I'm probably missing something; I don't remember what I did when I plugged in that spare a long time ago.)

My zpool status:

```bash
garyo@freenas ~ % zpool status -v freenas-boot                                                       
  pool: freenas-boot
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
    repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:07:03 with 0 errors on Wed Sep 27 03:52:03 2023
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    freenas-boot                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
      mirror-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
        gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c  FAULTED    360   784 1.25K  too many errors
        da0p2                                       ONLINE       0     0     0
garyo@freenas ~ % glabel status           
                                      Name  Status  Components
gptid/15d4bdc4-037a-11e8-a55f-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  ada1p2
gptid/c54977e0-a84a-11ec-afcf-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  ada2p2
gptid/e1ed945e-120b-11e5-a9c7-d0509964c14c     N/A  ada3p2
gptid/ea0b7cb6-b62d-11e8-ae87-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  ada4p2
gptid/e853ce91-d824-11e9-a2bf-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  ada0p2
gptid/9b05f414-a969-11e8-b9d0-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  ada5p2
gptid/64b18a04-428f-11ed-a6f7-0cc47ada24f0     N/A  da0p1
gptid/5fe47459-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c     N/A  da2p1
gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c     N/A  da2p2
```

Per comments, here are complete `zpool status` and `gpart show`:

```
garyo@freenas ~ % zpool status
  pool: freenas-boot
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
    repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:07:03 with 0 errors on Wed Sep 27 03:52:03 2023
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    freenas-boot                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
      mirror-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
        gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c  FAULTED    360   784 1.25K  too many errors
        da0p2                                       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: volume1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 07:18:41 with 0 errors on Sun Sep 24 07:19:13 2023
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    volume1                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/15d4bdc4-037a-11e8-a55f-0cc47ada24f0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/e853ce91-d824-11e9-a2bf-0cc47ada24f0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/e1ed945e-120b-11e5-a9c7-d0509964c14c  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/c54977e0-a84a-11ec-afcf-0cc47ada24f0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/ea0b7cb6-b62d-11e8-ae87-0cc47ada24f0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/9b05f414-a969-11e8-b9d0-0cc47ada24f0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
garyo@freenas ~ % gpart show
=>        40  5860533088  ada1  GPT  (2.7T)
          40          88        - free -  (44K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338688     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)
  5860533120           8        - free -  (4.0K)

=>        40  5860533088  ada2  GPT  (2.7T)
          40          88        - free -  (44K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338696     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)

=>        34  5860533101  ada3  GPT  (2.7T)
          34          94        - free -  (47K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338696     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)
  5860533128           7        - free -  (3.5K)

=>        40  5860533088  ada4  GPT  (2.7T)
          40          88        - free -  (44K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338688     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)
  5860533120           8        - free -  (4.0K)

=>        40  5860533088  ada0  GPT  (2.7T)
          40          88        - free -  (44K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338696     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)

=>        40  5860533088  ada5  GPT  (2.7T)
          40          88        - free -  (44K)
         128     4194304     1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  5856338688     2  freebsd-zfs  (2.7T)
  5860533120           8        - free -  (4.0K)

=>      40  60088240  da0  GPT  (29G)
        40      1024    1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
      1064  60087216    2  freebsd-zfs  (29G)

=>      34  31260605  da2  GPT  (15G)
        34      1024    1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
      1058         6       - free -  (3.0K)
      1064  31259568    2  freebsd-zfs  (15G)
  31260632         7       - free -  (3.5K)
```

As you can see, `da1` is not listed in any of these.

Here's `geom disk list`:

```
garyo@freenas ~ % geom disk list
Geom name: ada1
Providers:
1. Name: ada1
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0
   lunid: 50014ee2b94bee1c
   ident: WD-WCC4N0FZ3NH7
   rotationrate: 5400
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada2
Providers:
1. Name: ada2
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: ST3000VN007-2AH16M
   lunid: 5000c500dd0879ef
   ident: ZGYA0B7L
   rotationrate: 5980
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada3
Providers:
1. Name: ada3
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0
   lunid: 50014ee20bbb2625
   ident: WD-WCC4N5UTA8PK
   rotationrate: 5400
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada4
Providers:
1. Name: ada4
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: WDC WD30EFRX-68N32N0
   lunid: 50014ee26543ab32
   ident: WD-WCC7K0CTHAAH
   rotationrate: 5400
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada0
Providers:
1. Name: ada0
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: ST3000VN007-2E4166
   lunid: 5000c500b4c1d6dc
   ident: Z731DW8S
   rotationrate: 5900
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada5
Providers:
1. Name: ada5
   Mediasize: 3000592982016 (2.7T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r2w2e5
   descr: ST3000VN007-2E4166
   lunid: 5000c500b14c80da
   ident: Z730VD95
   rotationrate: 5900
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: da0
Providers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 30765219840 (29G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r1w1e2
   descr: USB SanDisk 3.2Gen1
   lunname: USB     SanDisk 3.2Gen1040103a910eedcc1a6d4
   lunid: USB     SanDisk 3.2Gen1040103a910eedcc1a6d4
   ident: 040103a910eedcc1a6d45a2a6e838a4e4714cab19e8b6afb4d329bce64703205b94e000000000000000000007d363e77001a55188155810715ad1af9
   rotationrate: unknown
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 255

Geom name: da1
Providers:
1. Name: da1
   Mediasize: 31458328576 (29G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: Generic Flash Disk
   lunname: ALCOR   ALCOR
   lunid: 200049454505080f
   ident: CD32FA3E
   rotationrate: unknown
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 255

Geom name: da2
Providers:
1. Name: da2
   Mediasize: 16005464064 (15G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: SanDisk Cruzer Fit
   lunname: SanDisk Cruzer Fit      4C530012850910111431
   lunid: SanDisk Cruzer Fit      4C530012850910111431
   ident: 4C530012850910111431
   rotationrate: unknown
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot replace a vdev member which is a partition with the entire device. I mean, formally speaking, ***you can***, but ***this will complicate things*** further, because you will suddenly get a non-bootable server when attempting to boot from second drive.

You need to properly label your replacement disk, then create the appropriate number of properly sized partitions and only then replace failed drive.

Right now your initial post is missing the `gpart show` output along with the non-cut output of `zpool status`, preventing you from receiving further instructions.

**Update:**

First of all, you are attempting to replace a bigger drive with a smaller one: da0 is already a part of the active mirror, and it's bigger than da2. Rgardless of the approach, this is technically impossible.

Second - regarding theis size - what atre those ? USB sticks ? This may be an entirely bad idea- to use system drive from USB sticks in a mirror.

Comment: Thanks @drookie -- I added those commands' output. I don't recall having to manually format replacement drives before when I've had to do this. I guess I expect truenas to do that when I do "replace" and select da1 in the UI... ?

Comment: I did try with the main partition on da1, with the same error: `sudo zpool replace freenas-boot gptid/5fef18d4-8588-11e5-8e5d-d0509964c14c /dev/da1p2`

Comment: Yeah, I know using USB sticks is a bad idea -- I'll migrate to something better as I have time.

Comment: I agree that it's weird that da0 (32GB) is bigger than da2 (16GB). But da2 is the faulting drive; I'm trying to replace it with da1 which is 32GB. I don't think that's where my error is coming from.

Comment: Then add the `geom disk list` output also.

Comment: done -- see post

Comment: Also `gpart list da1` looks pretty much the same as for da0. Two partitions, one boot and one zfs. But I do note that da1p2's mode is "r0w0e0" while da0p2's is "r1w1e1". May be significant?

Comment: I removed & reformatted the stick, tried a bunch of things, and seem to have got it working ok now. Thanks for the help!