# Enlarged my TrueNAS boot pool instead of mirroring. How can I fix it?

Tags: zfs, truenas

In [Problems trying to replace disk in truenas mirrored boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/1144575), I was trying to fix a failed drive on my mirrored TrueNAS boot pool. I flailed around and eventually got it booted with just one drive of the mirror (detached the other failed one).
But then, stupidly, instead of `zpool attach` I used `zpool add` and now I have a double-size but zero-redundancy boot pool!

So how can I get it back to being mirrored? I know it's not going to be simple. Maybe I can create a new pool (I do have extra drives etc.), copy the data over, and make that pool the boot pool? I have no idea how to do that. Anyone?
Or perhaps there's a way for me to add a third disk as a mirror of the other two? I'm guessing not, that seems like it would be complicated to manage anyway.

And through all of this I'm hoping my freenas will still boot. If I hose it, I'll have to figure out how to restore from backup.

Comment: Maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly. Maybe I should reinstall truenas onto a single drive (and set up mirroring) and then just re-upload my config backup?

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: TrueNAS and ZFS boot are a mess.